# Prevent PHP parsing <?code?> in strings

Tags: php, parsing, escaping

I currently have a database with some fields that contain text of the form

`The root location is <?=$GLOBALS['root']?>`,

the idea being that when displayed on the webpage the output is

`The root location is /random/directory/that/changes/`.

The problem is that I also want a page where these fields can be edited and so I need to put

`The root location is <?=$GLOBALS['root']?>`

into a textarea. Unfortunately, code like

```
<textarea><?echo $page->text?></textarea>
```

does what you'd expect and changes any occurances of `<?=$GLOBALS['root']?>` to /random/directory/that/changes/. I know it's possible to do this as phpmyadmin does it, but I've had a look at their code and can't quite work out how exactly they've done it. As far as I can tell, none of the usual escape functions on their own does the trick, as I expected they wouldn't.

P.S. I realise that putting PHP code into a database like that isn't exactly the best idea, but I'm kind of stuck with it now.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm a fool. Please disregard this question. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: why are you stuck with it? what about a template engine?

Comment: Also, exec'ing isn't exactly a great idea either.

Comment: No, it does not work the way you described. When you use PHP to render a webpage and `<?php ?>` is contained in a string, it will **not** be parsed by the PHP interpreter.

Comment: PHP code does not magically run in text strings retrieved from the database. Somewhere it is evaled already, so find out where that is, and disable it on whatever condition.

Comment: you said that you know that writing PHP code into a database isn't a good idea. I would say that it goes way beyond that, past "very bad idea" and "terrible idea", into the realm of "truly catastrophic idea". Seriously, if you can avoid doing this, please please do. A simple template engine really isn't that difficult. This is pretty much the worst possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

`<?php echo $page->text; ?>` should not be executing PHP code in `$page->text`. However, the PHP code inside of it may be interpreted *by the browser* as a [processing instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction). To fix that, you'd need to escape it as HTML:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($page->text); ?>
```

For more information on `htmlspecialchars`, [see the documentation](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce your own syntax for variables inside strings and run `str_replace` (or use regular expressions) to replace them with the actual values:

```
$variables = array(
  'root' => '/random/directory/that/changes/'
};
$string = str_replace('{$root}', $variables['root'], $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm an idiot and didn't read the code I've been left to deal with carefully enough. You are all correct in that the replacement wasn't automatically done by PHP, but for some reason the previous author thought to use `str_replace("<?=\$GLOBALS['root']?>", $GLOBALS['root'], mysql_result($result, 0, "text"));`...

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: small victory: you aren't actually exec-ing php code stored in the db. Your predecessor effectively chose to use php syntax for variable markers inside the "template" code. Some find and replace in the db - and @knittl's suggestion will likely save some sanity.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes("").
To put data into DB use some abstraction layer e.g. PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: But I can't put `$page->text` in double quotes otherwise I'll end up with `$page->text` as my output. I kind of what it to parse down one level and then stop.

Comment: So you probably need eval() as they wrote up there but eval()ing code is mostly bad idea. It might make very messy code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the `eval()` function to execute arbitrary code from the database. However, it is not recommended to execute arbitrary code from strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

The problem with `<?` goes away, since `eval()` doesn't support those.

Comment: Don't use `eval` unless you don't have any other choice.

Comment: @PLB agreed. But executing arbitrary code from strings isn't the safest thing in the world.

Comment: @AD7six I'm reading between the lines here. Based on his use case, it seems like `eval()` would take care of what he wants to do. I'm not sure how his code works as-is. I didn't think PHP executed code from strings without using `eval()`. That would seem like a bigger security hole.

Comment: `<textarea><?echo $something ?></textarea>` (weird syntax) won't recursively execute `$something` - For the question as written to be in some way valid - he's probably already eval'ing or including a tmp file with this content.

Comment: @AD7six yep, those were my thoughts too. It appears that the code wasn't doing what he thought it was, based on his update.